# Prisma has detected that this project was built on Vercel

Tags: nestjs, prisma, vercel

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to deploy my Nest.js project on Vercel. I've encountered an error message in the Vercel logs that I can't quite figure out how to resolve:

```
Starting Nest application...
AppModule dependencies initialized
UploadModule dependencies initialized
ERROR    Prisma has detected that this project was built on Vercel, which caches 
dependencies. This leads to an outdated Prisma Client because Prisma's auto-generation isn't
 triggered. To fix this, make sure to run the `prisma generate` command during the build process.

Learn how: https://pris.ly/d/vercel-build
```

Here's a bit of context on my project's setup:

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx prisma generate && nest build" ,
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Other dependencies...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // Dev dependencies...
  }
}
```

**`vercel.json`**

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "DELETE",
        "OPTIONS"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not entirely sure whether the `vercel.json` configuration is causing this problem. Could someone help me understand what might be causing the Prisma Client to become outdated during the Vercel deployment process?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!